# Cross-sectional weight in a time-series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe that stores time-series values in a wide tabular:

```
market_value = pd.DataFrame( {'AAPL':[100,200,400], 'IBM':[50,100,200],'MSFT':[50,200,400]},
                             index = ['2013-12-31', '2014-12-31', '2015-12-31'] )

In  [1]: market_value
Out [1]:
            AAPL    IBM    MSFT
2013-12-31   100     50      50
2014-12-31   200    100     200
2015-12-31   400    200     400
```

I want to calculate the cross-sectional weight for each stock at any given point of time.  For example on 2013-12-31, the weight of AAPL is:

```
100 / (100+50+50) = 0.50
```

So the result should look like this:

```
In  [2]: weight
Out [2]:
            AAPL    IBM    MSFT
2013-12-31  0.50   0.25    0.25
2014-12-31  0.40   0.20    0.40
2015-12-31  0.40   0.20    0.40
```

In Matlab this is done by:

```
weight = market_value ./ repmat( sum(market_value,2), 1, 3 )
```

What's the most elegant way of doing this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) by rows:

```
print (market_value.sum(axis=1))
2013-12-31     200
2014-12-31     500
2015-12-31    1000
dtype: int64

print (market_value.div(market_value.sum(axis=1), axis=0))
            AAPL   IBM  MSFT
2013-12-31   0.5  0.25  0.25
2014-12-31   0.4  0.20  0.40
2015-12-31   0.4  0.20  0.40
```